# invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' -fpermissive c++ ASCII function

Tags: c++, string, ascii

I've got function which should check if 4 characters in string are next ASCII codes like: A5mnpoR89cd where mnpo is the answer. Here is my code:

```
bool trzecie(string a,string b, string c, string d)
{
string x = a + b + c + d;
sort(x.begin(), x.end());
if((int)x.at(0) == (int)x.at(1) - 1 == (int)x.at(2) - 2 == (int)x.at(3) - 3)
{
    return true;
}
else return false;
}

int main()
{
ifstream wejscie("hasla.txt");
string tab[200];
vector <string> vec;

for(int i=0; i<200; i++)
{
    wejscie>>tab[i];
}

int licz_b = 0;
for(int i=0; i<200; i++)
{
    string x = tab[i];
    for(int j=3; j<x.size(); j++)
    {
        if( trzecie( x.at(j),  x.at(j-1) , x.at(j-2), x.at(j-3)) ) //ERROR HERE
        {
            if(!trzecie( x.at(j),  x.at(j-1) , x.at(j-2), x.at(j+1))) // AND HERE
            {
                licz_b++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
cout<<"C. "<<licz_b<<endl;
}
```

and i've got error invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' -fpermissive
in highlighted lines. what is the problem? I tried to change

```
x.at(j)
```

to:

```
x[j]
```

but it didn't work either; /:

Any other options?

Comment: `x.at(j)` and `x[j]` both provide the character at index `j`. `char` is not implicitly convertible to `std::string`. Perhaps you meant for `trzecie` to accept 4 `char`s instead of 4 `std::string`s. Otherwise, you can use the `substring` method.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux i used 4 chars and it works better, thanks, its easier to write something like that

Comment: `A == B == C == D` does not check that the four quantities are all equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function has the signature

```
bool trzecie(string a,string b, string c, string d)
```

The proper way to construct a `string` from a `char` is

```
std::string str(1, char);
```

So those lines should be

```
if( trzecie( string(1, x.at(j)),  string(1, x.at(j-1)), string(1, x.at(j-2)), string(1, x.at(j-3))))
```

Comment: I feel a better solution would be to change `trzecie` to take 4 `char` instead, it seems to currently expect four `std::string` of 1 character each. Additionally, the usage provides four `char`.